# DynamoDB optimized search for common parent

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

So Im designing currently three tables, an organization, organization_relationships, members.

| Organization |
| --- |
| OrgID PK |
| Metdata.. |

| Org_Relationships |
| --- |
| ParentOrgID PK |
| ChildOrgID Range/GSI |

| Member |
| --- |
| OrgID PK |
| MemberID Range/GSI |

One way that I need to access data, is by determining whether two members share a parent organization. With the way this is right now, I would basically have to do a weird search on the tables, that requires multiple calls to the table to determine whether two members belong to the same parent organization. With that being said is there a more efficient way of designing the table to do this without requiring multiple calls to the table.

Comment: Do you know the organization name ahead of time, or just the member names?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan just the member names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having to perform multiple queries is because you've modeled the relationship across several tables.  This is a common approach when using traditional relational databases, but could be considered an anti-pattern with NoSQL databases.

Keep in mind that DynamoDB does not have a join operation like SQL databases.  Therefore, it is a best practice to store related data in the same DynamoDB table.  This can be counter-intuitive if you're used to working with relational DBs.

There are several ways to model your data in DynamoDB.  The approach you choose depends on your access patterns.  In other words, you store your data in a way that makes it easier to get the data your application needs.

For example, here's one way to model Users and Organizations:

[image]

The primary key is made up of a user id (e.g. USER#) and a sort key of META.  This record (called an "item") in DynamoDB is where I'll define various user attributes.  In this example, I've provided a name and an org attribute.

For illustrative purposes, I've also created a global secondary index (GSI) that swaps the partition key/sort key pattern in your base table.  Your GSI will look like this:

[image]

This lets you fetch all users by organization.

If I wanted to check if two users are in the same organization, I can either query the GSI, or fetch both user records and compare the org fields.

This is just an example meant to give you a starting point with NoSQL design.  The key takeaways here are:

1. NoSQL (or non-relational) data modeling is different than SQL (relational) data modeling.
2. You want to store related data in the same table.
3. How you store your data depends entirely on how you plan to use the data.